# How can I host multiple html files present in different locations on nginx server

Tags: nginx, webserver, web-hosting

I have 2 index.html files present in 2 different folders. How can I map my nginx to point to these different folders either by port and location based mapping??

I have tried creating single file in sites-available folder and mapping their directories under `location / {` but it didn't work

I have:

2 html files at

```
/var/www/ex1.com/index.html

/var/www/ex2.com/index.html
```

I would like to do is:

```
ip:8080 ex1/index.html gets rendered

ip:8081 ex2/index.html gets rendered
```

And also how can I achieve this

```
ip/ex1 goes to ex1/index.html

ip/ex2 goes to ex2/index.html
```

Comment: What is the URI of each of these files?

Comment: @RichardSmith I have restructured my question for better understanding

Comment: You need three servers, each listening on a different port: 80, 8080 and 8081. That would require three `server` blocks, in the same file or separate files (makes no difference). What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using location / { option within the server and writing listen 8080 and listen 8081 in their server block file

Comment: Please edit your question and add the complete `server` blocks. Show the relevant entries from the access and error logs.

Comment: You didn't get my question, using server blocks and changing local /etc/hosts file. I was able to access different html files. But how can I re-write my server blocks such away that I can access the same using server IP and port number....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure an Nginx server to listen to a specific port, use the `listen` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#listen) for details.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 8080;
    root /var/www/ex1.com;
}
server {
    listen 8081;
    root /var/www/ex2.com;
}
```

---

The URLs `http://<ip_address>/ex1` and `http://<ip_address>/ex2` will be processed  by the same `server` block, listening on port 80.

You will need to use the `alias` directive instead of the `root` directive, as the path to the local file cannot be created by simple concatenation of some value with the URI.

For example:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    location /ex1 {
        alias /var/www/ex1.com;
    }
    location /ex2 {
        alias /var/www/ex2.com;
    }
}
```

Note that both the `location` value and the `alias` value should have a trailing `/` or neither have a trailing `/`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for details.

Comment: That helped!! Thanks